# Prevent double submits form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form which has a submit button. If I click this submit button then JSON will be posted to a webservice through AJAX:

```
$("#msform").submit(function (e) {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://example.com/webservice',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData1,
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

});
```

The webpage will also load and go to another page.. While loading the user can click multiple times on the Submit button, if he does that then for multiple times the AJAX post will be done to the webservice.

I tried this code to fix this but it does not work:

```
// jQuery plugin to prevent double submission of forms
jQuery.fn.preventDoubleSubmission = function () {
    $(this).on('submit', function (e) {
        var $form = $(this);

        if ($form.data('submitted') === true) {
            // Previously submitted - don't submit again
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            // Mark it so that the next submit can be ignored
            $form.data('submitted', true);
        }
    });

    // Keep chainability
    return this;
};

$('#msform').preventDoubleSubmission();
```

Any idea why double posting is not prevented??

Comment: Disable the submit element? this prevents it being clicked again and is a visual cue to the user that something is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use a `variable` called `wasSubmitted` which verify if `ajax` request was already sent.

```
 var wasSubmitted = false;
 $("#msform").submit(function (e) {
    if(!wasSubmitted) {
        wasSubmitted = true;
        $.ajax({
           url: 'https://example.com/webservice',
           type: 'POST',
           data: formData1,
           crossDomain: true,
           dataType: 'json',
           jsonpCallback: 'callback',
           success: function (data) {
             console.log(data);
           }
       });
       return wasSubmitted;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Does not work, if I go in to the chrome inspect and then put a breakpoint on $(this).unbind('click'); and then click multiple times on submit then it still sends and still goes through the submit code for multiple times

Comment: @bboni, Yes, sorry. I edited my answer. You have to use `.unbind` for button element. I used `$('button')` but you can replace with your `selector`. Suppose you have button with id=`btn`, then you can use this :`$('#btn').unbind('click')`;

Comment: It still submits multiple times :(

Answer (score -1):

I think a simple preventDefault would be enough

```
$("#msform").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax(..)
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution, that comes to my mind first, is to disable the button onclick with JS.

```
document.getElementById("btn_id").setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
```

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. It would work for ajax submissions, but not regular form submissions.